# How to get curl/curl.h in curl?

Tags: c++, c, curl, libcurl

I downloaded curl to use [webdriverxx](https://github.com/sekogan/webdriverxx#unicode).

I compiled after insert, but there is about 70 error `saying that cannot open the file curl/curl.h.`

There is a header file called `curl.h` in the curl I downloaded, but there is no header file called c`url/curl.h`. So I searched Google, but I don't know where to get the file.

Comment: How are you compling? Have you provided the include directory? Are you using curl as a static or a dynamic library? Please provide details.

Comment: I downloaded curl-7.68.0-win64-mingw at https://curl.haxx.se/download.html#Win32 and i copied A header file called curl.h in the folder  into my project directory

Answer (score 0):

Can you tell which OS are you using?

If you found the *curl.h* file in the https://github.com/sekogan/webdriverxx#unicode but don't see it in the file you have downloaded, try to copy the *curl.h* content from github, create another *curl.h* file in the correct path (*/curl/* like you said) and paste the file content you have copied from to github to your *curl.h* file.

**Some other things you can do:**

- Redownload the file (remember to delete clearly the old file)
- Create an issue on the repository
- Make sure that you have downloaded the file in the correct path and run it in the correct path
- Remember again did you missing something (did you download it normally, is there any error appears when you were downloading it, have you read clearly the *README.md* file, there may be a download guide in that file, ...)

Comment: I downloaded curl-7.68.0-win64-mingw at curl.haxx.se/download.html#Win32 and i copied A header file called curl.h in the folder into my project directory. but Some header files in webdriverxx ask curl/curl.h as well as curl.h. But there is no header file of that name in curl-7.68.0-win64-mingw folder that I downloaded.

Comment: I did it maybe more 5 times downloading and deleting and downloading.

Comment: @MX-4 It seems you don't understand the difference between a file (`curl.h`) and a folder (`/curl/`). The code is trying to include the file `curl.h` located in a folder `/curl/` whose location is determined by the project's search paths.

Comment: @RemyLebeau So you mean that curl/curl.h is not exist and i only have to locate "curl.h" at Project directory?

Comment: @MX-4 it means you need to create a folder (aka directory) named `curl` and put the `curl.h` file into it. You can create the `curl` directory in your project directory. Or create it wherever you want, if you then configure the project makefile to specify the location of that directory to the compiler. Either way, the `curl` directory is required since the code mentions it explicitly. `/` is a directory separator, not part of the filename.

Comment: @Remy Lebeau Almost there. You don't need to create the `/curl/` directory. When you downloaded webdriverxx, the  `/curl/` directory has already there. Create a new folder can cause an error if the folder is not in the right place.